# Using Swagger, can one mark a field as 'readOnly' for one request and modifiable for another without cloning the schema?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I have 2 API calls for creating and updating a particular record. We would like to express one can specify a value or have it be generated for a specific field on create, but cannot modify it on update.

The only solution I see is to have a model for update and create, but this just creates extra schemas to maintain.

Is there a cleaner way to handle this?